# Can hydrogen be used for superconductors?

Tags: superconductivity, hydrogen

I learned that heaver isotopes of a substance have a lower superconductivity transition temperature. Does this mean that things like hydrogen which are lighter can be used for high temperature superconductors?

Comment: Have you thought about what phase hydrogen is in at "high" temperatures?

Comment: Superconducting transition temperatures depend on many things in addition to the mass of the isotopes.

Comment: The downvote is most certainly not deserved. See answer below.

Answer (score 7):

In fact hydrogen is an old idea to get a high temperature superconductor, based exactly on the idea of its light mass.

The problem is that one has to start from metallic hydrogen, which is a problem on itself. It has not yet been fully experimentally confirmed in the lab. You need pressures of several hundreds of GPa to achieve that (100 GPa is about 1 million times the atmospheric pressure).

However, very recently a group in Germany suceeded in producing a hydrogen based superconductor at 200 K. The largest ever measured critical temperature for a superconductor. The report is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08190) and it was published in nature this month. They got superconductivity in H$_2$S, a substance that smell like rotten eggs. The caveat is that they had to go to 200 GPa to observe it.

In short, the lightness of hydrogen makes is a very good candidate to achieve high temperature superconductivity. The experimental conditions to obtain it are quite complicated, though. It is unlikely (not impossible) that this will lead to a practical application.